# Clicking a link in a TextView that is part of an adapter in android

Tags: android

I am designing a chatting app where I am required to make links clickable inside a TextView. I have used **android:autoLink="all"** in TextView to distinguish links/phones etc.

This works up to displaying the part of TextView that are links/phones as clickable but when I click it, I get the following exception:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

I searched a bit and it seems that I need to pass the activity context while inflating the TextView from XML. But how can I do that as i am inflating this view inside an adapter? This TextView is part of card view that is part of a recycler view in an adapter.

Comment: When you want the context() inside an adapter you use parent.getContext();

Comment: show your code where you want to start new activity.

Comment: Also try

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: I tried intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) but it didn't work. Got the same exception.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `layoutInflater.inflate()` to inflate the view, I used `LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate()` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the Parent Activity to start a new activity from adapter or set the Intent flag.

For parent activity pass the Activity to Adapter's Construcutor and initialize it to use in the adatper like this.

in you MainActivity

```
Activity activity = this;
MyAdapter _adpater = new MyAdapter(....., activity);
```

in MyAdapter class

```
//constructor
Activity activity;
public MyAdapter (......, Activity _activity) {
        ........
        this.activity= _activity;
    }
```

now you can use this activity to start new activity.

`activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity,target.class));`

or you can try setting the flag with your current method.

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext, target.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

Comment: I am using the the following to start the activity:

parent.getContext().startActivity(intent);

Comment: try any of the above two solutions and let me know.

Comment: I tried both but to no avail. Btw, do i need to specify what to open on clicking a link? Or android will automatically open the clicked URL in a browser?